# Proving the least number of times an item will appear in a sequence

Tags: proof-verification, modular-arithmetic

I have to prove the following:

> If the letters `a` to `g` are written down 100 times, where the sequence doesn't matter, prove that at least one of the letters have to be written out at least 15 times

My solution for this so far is realising there are $7$ numbers, written 100 times.

$$100 \ \div \ 7 \ \text{~} \ 14$$
$$100 \ \% \ 7 = 2$$

So if all letters are written 14 times, we will have 98 letters occurring 14 times each, leaving 2 letters left to be written, so we must write either one letter two more times or two letters one more time, therefore at least one letter will be written 15 times.

This is all I have, but I'm assuming all the letters are being written 7 times, which is incorrect I think.

Am I on the right track? I would appreciate any hints or tips, but not the full answer as I'd like to tackle this on my own.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the phrase "at most".

If no letter were written 15 times then all are written *at most* 14 times and the longest possible sequence would be at most 7x14 =98 letters long.  As we were told it was 100 letters long this is impossible.

Btw study up on the "pigeon hole principle".

====

Here's another valid argument.

The average number of times each letter is used is 14 2/7.  It's not possible that *all* values are below average.  So one letter is used at least 14 2/7 times or more.  As letters can only be used a whole number of times so one letter at least must be used at least 15 times.

Comment: Is that the full answer?

Comment: What more do you think you need?  Note:  you are not making any assumptions about how many times any letter is used.  It could be that all letters but e are never used and e is used 100 times.  Or that a through e are used exactly 14 times and f and g 15.  Or any combination.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea.  All you need to do to turn it into a complete proof is express your ideas in terms of inequalities.  That is, instead of supposing that each letter is used $14$ times, suppose that each letter is used *at most* $14$ times.  This is exactly the negation of "at least one letter is used at least $15$ times", so if you can prove this is impossible then you are done.